# How to convert clustering simple plot to region coloring plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I have this plot for my clusterin,[image] and it is my code to plot this:

```
y_pred = KMeans(n_clusters=4,
                random_state=random_state).fit_predict(X_train_pca)

plt.scatter(X_train_pca[:, 0], X_train_pca[:, 1], c=y_pred)

plt.title("Unevenly Sized Blobs")

plt.show()
```

But I want to change it as that background has the color. I mean, it shows regions something like this[image]

I really appreciate any help that you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on scikit-learn's [demo for plotting kmeans decision boundaries](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_digits.html#visualize-the-results-on-pca-reduced-data):

1. Modify your current code to store the `KMeans` model so we can use the fitted model later to color the decision surface. Here it's stored as lowercase `kmeans`.

   ```py
   kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4, random_state=random_state)
   y_pred = kmeans.fit_predict(X_train_pca)
   plt.scatter(X_train_pca[:, 0], X_train_pca[:, 1], c=y_pred, cmap='Dark2')
   ```
2. Construct an underlying [`meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) from `X_train_pca` and use `kmeans.predict` to label the entire mesh. Then use [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) to plot this mesh in color.

   ```py
   # step size of mesh (decrease h to increase plot quality)
   h = 0.02

   # construct mesh
   x_min, x_max = X_train_pca[:, 0].min() - 1, X_train_pca[:, 0].max() + 1
   y_min, y_max = X_train_pca[:, 1].min() - 1, X_train_pca[:, 1].max() + 1
   xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

   # obtain labels per mesh point (reuse stored model)
   Z = kmeans.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

   # put result into color plot
   Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
   plt.imshow(
       Z, interpolation='nearest', cmap='Set2', alpha=0.75,
       extent=(xx.min(), xx.max(), yy.min(), yy.max()),
       aspect='auto', origin='lower',
   )
   ```

I don't have your original data, but this is the output from some random training data:

[image: kmeans plot with decision boundaries]